# Error when converting IR kinect image to CvImage using cv_bridge

Tags: kinect, opencv, openni, opencv2, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am trying to obtain the IR images (of type `const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& image`) from the kinect, copy this image to a class attribute `ImageIn_`, and then convert it to an opencv type image using cv_bridge so I can do some processing:   `imageOut_ = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(imageIn_, enc::MONO16);`

The compilation is successful but when running the node, I keep getting this error message: `[ERROR] [1361153962.171443742]: Unable to convert '' image to bgr8: 'Unrecognized image encoding []'`

I am not sure why its trying to convert it to `bgr8` and not `mono16`. I have also tried  `imageOut_ = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(imageIn_, enc::BGR8);` but I still get the same error.

I am also not sure why it is not recognizing the image encoding, I printed out the input image encoding in the callback function : `ROS_INFO("imageIn_Time = %s", imageIn_->encoding.c_str() );`, it prints out `mono16`.

I am not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. I am using ROS Fuerte and Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55448/error-when-converting-ir-kinect-image-to-cvimage-using-cv_bridge/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-02-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was to remove the enc::MONO16 from the toCvVopy function `imageOut_ = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(imageIn_)` and then convert the image to type CV_U8C1 `imageOut_->image.covertTo(imageOut_->image, CV_8UC1)`

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Median](https://answers.ros.org/users/4366/median/) on 2013-03-11**:
Can you please share the whole code? I have the exact same problem and your solution is not working. If I try to run toCvCopy without a 2nd argument I get the same exception (Unrecognized enconding).

**Comment by [Median](https://answers.ros.org/users/4366/median/) on 2013-03-12**:
I don't understand what ImageIn_ is .. is it a cv_bridge::CvImagePtr ??

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-03-12**:
imageIn_ is a sensor_msgs::ImageConstPt , imageOut_ is a cv_bridge::CvImagePtr

**Comment by [saips](https://answers.ros.org/users/20045/saips/) on 2014-08-19**:
yup , this one works